# Getting Geolocation working with JQM/phone gap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an application using phonegap and jQM. i'm trying to get my geolocation to work when clicking the button but i get an error in the console saying geolocation is not defined.
The error is pointing to the onclick="getLocation()". Can anyone help me please?

Heres an example of my code:

```
  <div data-role="page" id="geo" data-add-back-btn="true" onload="onBodyLoad()">
        <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Geolocation</h1>
        </header>
        <div data-role="content">
            <button data-role="button" onclick="getLocation()">Click to get your current position</button>

            <div id="mapholder"></div> 
        </div> 

    </div>


$("#geo").on('pageinit', function () {
console.log("Geo page loaded!");

function onBodyLoad(){      
    document.getElementById('geolocation').empty();
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady(){
     phoneGapReady.innerHTML = ("")
}

var x=document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
        }else {
            x.innerHTML="Your Browser does not support Geolocation.";}
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
        lat=position.coords.latitude;
        lon=position.coords.longitude;
        latlon=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
        mapholder=document.getElementById('mapholder')
        mapholder.style.height='250px';
        mapholder.style.width='100%';

        var myOptions= {
            center:latlon,zoom:14,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl:false,
            navigationControlOptions:
            {style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
        };

        var map = new
            google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"),myOptions);
        var marker=new
            google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"Your Location."});
      }

      function showError(error)
      {
          switch(error.code) 
          {
              case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
              x.innerHTML="User did not allow Geolocation."
              break;
              case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
              x.innerHTML="Location Data is not Available."
              break;
              case error.TIMEOUT:
              x.innerHTML="Request Timed Out."
              break;
              case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
              x.innerHTML="Unknown Error."
              break;
          }
      }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Phonegap 3.x, make sure you've added the geolocation plugin to your project:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
```

Make sure the config.xml includes it:

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
</feature>
```

Make sure you allow access in the android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Try changing

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
```

to

```
if (typeof(navigator.geolocation) != "undefined") {
```